# jRuby / Rails proper syntax for if-else with AND/OR

Tags: if-statement, jruby

What is the proper syntax with Ruby for an IF statement that has multiple constraints.

example in php you could do.

```
if(($something == $this) AND ($this == $that))
```

So I am looking for the Ruby rendition of that syntax. I try to search for it, but since its common words, and most search engines use the same words for conditionals my searches come up with very litte.

Comment: Did you search for "ruby operators" ?

Comment: No unfortunatley the term evaded me, I was super tired at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually tried anything?

The syntax isn't that far from php:

```
if ((2 % 2 == 0) and (3 % 2 == 1))
  puts "2 is even, 3 is not"
end
```

You should probably read up on [Ruby's if syntax](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Flow_Control#The_Ruby_if_Statement)

Answer (score 1):

```
if something == this && this == that
```

or

```
if something == this and this == that
```

You should [be careful](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2008/12/08/and-vs-amperand-in-ruby) using `and` though.